# Proof that curl of a vector is non-zero if loop integral is proved to be

Tags: vectors, vector-analysis, vector-fields

Consider a force of form $\vec F=N\hat v$, where $\hat v$ is a unit vector in direction of velocity or equivalently, in direction  of change of displacement and N is a constant. To prove that this is a path-dependent force we will consider the integral
$$\oint\vec F\cdot d\vec r$$
Where $d\vec r$ is displacement in any general direction. Since the direction of force and displacement are the same we get that
$$\oint\vert\vec F\vert\vert d\vec r\vert$$ Making it clear that this indeed is path-dependent.

The question is can we prove this using the curl form of the integral, that is in general
$$\vec\nabla\times\vec F\neq0?$$

Also, can we generalize to this where N is some scalar function instead of a constant?

Comment: Velocity and displacement are not equivalent. Do you mean $\vec{F} = N \vec{r}/|\vec{r}|$?  Ignoring the fact this is undefined at the origin, this is a conservative force field, as $\vec{F} = N \vec{\nabla} |\vec{r}|$, and $\vec{\nabla} \times \vec{F} = 0$.

Comment: @RobertIsrael oops I meant change In displacement,  now corrected in original post. Also $d\vec r$ here is not a radial vector, but change in displacement vector.

Comment: So $\vec{F}$ is dependent on the path your particle is taking, not just on the position?  Then it is not a vector field, and there is no such thing as $\vec{\nabla} \times \vec{F}$.

Comment: @RobertIsrael Ah I see, I have made this mistake before too, that is I just know what I am doing is wrong but not why it is wrong. For example, the same issue was with this question https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/723224/330899. Can you guide me where to look further on this?